# failed to load platform rendering library any way

Tags: android

I have a problem with TextView android with this massage:
"failed to load platform rendering library android studio".
And not solve with changed the version of the preview.
Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try install other android SDK platform on SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try install other SDK platform in SDK manager.